# XAML ListView , how to load images only when item is visible

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a XAML listbox in my windows 8 metro application, this listbox is binded to an observable collection, and can have hundreds of items . it also has one image, i want to load the image only when an item is visible(when user scrolls to that item). 
how can i do this. ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the ItemPanelTemplate of your ListBox to put a VirtualizedStackPanel: the control will be virtualized and only the items displayed on screen will be loaded in memory.